# How to drop and create index constraints dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server

I work with a database with a plenty of tables. These tables do not have PK constraints, but each table has a column-candidate to be a PK-column (according to business logic its values are unique). To do more complex task I need to write a script to apply PK constraints to each table.

There are some difficulties that I faced with:

- column-candidates support NULL values (PK can not be NULL)
- to convert such columns to NOT NULL columns I need to remove and then recreate indexes affecting that columns
- the list of indexes is known only for stock version of the database and it can be modified by end-users

My algorytm for each table is below:

1. Drop indexes affecting column
2. Convert column to NOT NULL
3. Apply PK constraint
4. Restore indexes

Are there other approaches to do that? My question is how I can dynamically drop and restore indexes if I do not know the whole list of them on the moment of writing the script?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50127724/drop-and-recreate-constraints-script/50130793#50130793

Comment: This can be done using the catalog views. How do you identify the PK column(s)?

Comment: @killer-queen that is interesting solution.

Comment: @dan-guzman I have business requirements for each table.